# Similar to xkill for mir

Tags: testing, 15.04, xkill

**xkill** is a command I almost use everyday. That's because my PC is quite crappy [a 10' chilli GREEN netbook NEO XP made in Holland (even if I'm in Greece), with 1 GB ram memory and 2 Intel Atom cores and poor 3d acceleration]. I recently installed ubuntu NEXT 15.04 on my pc and sometimes some programs lag a lot. That's where I usually use Xkill BUT I'm not using x11 now, I'm using Mir. And I tried xkill but it says:

```
The program 'xkill' is not currently installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install x11-utils
```

But I'm not using x11 !!!

So, if I installed x11, would it work or not? And if not, is there any similar command for mir instead of xkill?

Comment: I know you want the graphical app for killing a window, but there's a command line alternative, `pkill app-name`, for example `pkill firefox` will kill all the open firefox windows. You can use that until you find something for mir

Comment: @David Foerster , done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you want the graphical app for killing a window, but there's a command line alternative, `pkill app-name`, for example

```
pkill firefox
```

will kill all the open firefox windows. You can use that until you find something for mir.